# Spring security jdbc user authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

I create my first web service using spring and hibernate.I created a login and want to secure it now using spring security.I went through the tutorials and based on them I tried to protect my website. However, with poor results. I created a database for the role of users and a configuration file springa security. The problem occurs when, for example, the address "/ my-account / basket" is only available for users with the user role. After logging in when I clicked on the "/ my-account / basket" link, the application moved me to the login panel.How can I fix it.Any suggestion would be helpful.

Database tables:

```
| login | CREATE TABLE login (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  login varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  repeatpassword varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

| userroles | CREATE TABLE `userroles` (
  `id_user_roles` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rolename` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user_roles`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `userroles_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `login` (`id`)
)
 
Controller:

```
@Controller("Logowanie")
```

@RequestMapping(value ="/my-account")
public class Login {

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value ="/sign-in")
public String Login(Model model){
    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("getUser",user);
    return "login-page";
}

@RequestMapping("/processForm")
public String showLoginPage(@Valid @ModelAttribute("getUser") User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap, HttpSession httpSession) throws NullPointerException{
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        if(userService.matchPasswords(user)){
            httpSession.setAttribute("login",user.getLogin());
            return "redirect:/my-account/user";
        }
        else {
            modelMap.addAttribute("message", "Nie poprwane logowanie");
            return "redirect:/my-account/error";
        }
    }
    else {
        modelMap.addAttribute("message","Zaloguj sie ponownie: Nie podales loginu lub hasla");
        return "redirect:/my-account/error";
    }
}
```

}

Spring Security Config:

```
    @Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select login,password,repeatpassword,email from login where login = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select l.login , ur.rolename from login l, userroles ur where l.id=ur.id and l.login = ?");

}

    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/my-account/basket")
            .hasAuthority("user")
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/my-account/sign-in")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/my-account/processForm")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/my-account/user")
            .failureUrl("/my-account/error")
            .usernameParameter("Login")
            .passwordParameter("Password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to the `@RequestMapping("/processForm")` you handle the login processing.
   The `formLogin` will register a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` with your settings.

   `// login page
   .loginPage("/my-account/sign-in")
   // processing url
   .loginProcessingUrl("/my-account/processForm")
   // go to this url when login success
   .defaultSuccessUrl("/my-account/user")
   .failureUrl("/my-account/error")
   // username & password parameter
   .usernameParameter("Login")
   .passwordParameter("Password")`
2. Make sure `select l.login , ur.rolename from login l, userroles ur where l.id=ur.id and l.login = ?` , the ur.rolename contains `user` autority.

   `.antMatchers("/my-account/basket")
   .hasAuthority("user")`

Comment: 1. So should i just delete this mapping or whole method ? 2. I checked in the database has the same value as in the .hasAuthority method